# Merge multiline strings in python

Tags: python, string, concatenation, newline

Trying to figure out how to merge multiple strings containing new lines.

so:

```
"""line 1 
line 2 
line 3 
line 4"""
```

+

```
"""addition 1 
addition 2 
addition 3 
addition 4"""
```

becomes

```
"""line 1 addition 1
line 2 addition 2
line 3 addition 3
line 4 addition 4"""
```

But with many more entries than just two.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post some code of what you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `list comprehension` and `join` to concatenate the strings:

```
s1 = """line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4"""

s2 = """addition 1
addition 2 
addition 3 
addition 4"""

result = "\n".join([" ".join(elem) for elem in zip(s1.split("\n"), s2.split("\n"))])
print(result)
```

Output:

```
line 1 addition 1
line 2 addition 2 
line 3 addition 3 
line 4 addition 4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split on new line, then zip/concat:

```
s1 = """line 1 
line 2 
line 3 
line 4"""

s2 = """addition 1 
addition 2 
addition 3 
addition 4"""

print('\n'.join(map(lambda l: l[0] + l[1],zip(s1.split('\n'), s2.split('\n')))))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
>>> L = '\n'.join(f'line {i}' for i in range(1, 5))
>>> A = '\n'.join(f'addition {i}' for i in range(1, 5))
>>> LA = '\n'.join(map(' '.join, zip(*map(str.split, (L, A), ('\n', '\n')))))
>>> 
>>> print(LA)
line 1 addition 1
line 2 addition 2
line 3 addition 3
line 4 addition 4
```

Explanation: using `split` and `join` we can split at newlines (or whatever character we choose) to get individual lines (as a list) and the reverse.

`map` is a way of applying the same function to multiple arguments. The inner `map` may look a bit frivolous, since it can essentially be rewritten `L.split('\n'), A.split('\n')`. However, since OP requests *many more entries than just two* `map` is actually a good choice here

`zip` I assume everybody knows, here it returns `('line 1', 'addition 1'), ('line 2', 'addition 2'), ...`

Next, we use `map` to apply `' '.join` to each of the pairs, which gives `'line 1 addition 1', 'line 2 addition 2', ...`

It remains to rejoin them with newlines.

Comment: Throwing a weaponized one-liner like this at an OP who's struggling to concatenate strings should be banned by the Geneva Conventions. Any chance you can make that monstrosity readable?

Comment: @Aran-Fey Touche! I'll try and add a walk-through.

Comment: Thanks for adding an explanation. I still don't like the code, but at least it's comprehensible now.